# how I can avoid file creation 2 times, only one file which content should be encoded base64 string

Tags: c#

- I have to loop list of strings and write each string in one line.
- then I have to encode it as base64 string for it and need to create a file.
- this file I will share encoded file with other program where **upon decode file content should show line by line**.

To do this,

- I am first creating a base file and write content line by line.
- then I am reading all the bytes of file.
- then creating a base64 string
- then write base64 string to a new file and deleting the base file

  ```
  var lstStr = new List<string>
           {
               "Hello1", "Hello2"
           };

           using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\TEMP\base_file.txt"))
           {
               foreach (var str in lstStr)
               {
                   //need to write data line by line
                   file.WriteLine(str);
               }
           }


           var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TEMP\base_file.txt");
           var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
           File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TEMP\base64_file.txt", base64String);

           //delete base file
           File.Delete(@"C:\TEMP\base_file.txt");
  ```

Now how I can avoid file creation 2 times, only one file which content should be encoded base64 string.

And when decode by other app, content should display line by line.

```
 var file = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TEMP\base64_file.txt");
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\TEMP\file.txt", Convert.FromBase64String(file));
```

> Hello1

Hello2

Comment: Why are you saving the original text to a file then? You could just keep the text in memory, encode it, and then save it to a file.

Comment: What does "line by line" mean in the context of a base-64 chunk that probably doesn't include line-endings? is the intention of the other app to parse the base-64 and *find* the original line-endings? if so... why? what purpose does the base-64 step serve here?

Comment: Is you question how to determine which file is encoded? Or you just want to avoid creating intermediate file and write encoded file once?

Comment: @Sinatr, wanted to avoid creating intermediate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming UTF-8 encoding of the string:

```
byte[] dataAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstStr));
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TEMP\base64_file.txt",  Convert.ToBase64String(dataAsBytes));
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and sweet

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `MemoryStream`.

This is your code changed to use it:

```
            var lstStr = new List<string>
            {
                "Hello1", "Hello2"
            };

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var file = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                foreach (var str in lstStr)
                {
                    //need to write data line by line
                    file.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }


            var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TEMP\base64_file.txt", base64String);
```